# Jquery if div toggled is already visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

i have a div that i want to toggle on click.If div is already visible i dont want my toggle function be executed. Here is my code and for some reasont it's not working propper.
[JsFiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/L1spx0pg/)

```
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
if ($("#toggled").is(":hidden"))
{
 $(".test" ).click(function() {
    $("#toggled").toggle();
    });
}
else
{

}
});
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: if div is visible and i press another button div should stay visible instead disappearing

Comment: [Use the `show` method instead of the `toggle`.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/L1spx0pg/1/)

Comment: yep seems it's working with show, but toggle can't be verified ?

Comment: Wrapping the event handler in that condition looks like you're not understanding how it works? -> http://fiddle.jshell.net/L1spx0pg/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jQuery's one method:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".test" ).one('click', function() {
        $("#toggled").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of work but finally

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var indexs = null;
    var bindIt = false;
    $("ul .test" ).click(function() {
        $("#toggled").show(); 
        if($(this).index() == indexs && bindIt == true){       
             $("#toggled").hide();
             bindIt = false;
         }else if(bindIt == false){
             indexs = $(this).index();
             bindIt = true;
         }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/L1spx0pg/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking this one. If you just want to show the div when a list item is clicked, the show function is all you need:

`$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".test").click(function () {
         $("#toggled").show();
     });
});`

Here's the updated **[jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cj03v4xt/)**.